# Number of degrees of freedom in a unitary transformation on a $n$-qubit register

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematics, quantum-computer

I was going thorough paper *[Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0407010.pdf)* by Mottonen et al. In that it says

> The configuration space of the $n$-qubit quantum register is $2^n$-dimensional complex space. Excluding the global phase and state normalization, we find that the general unitary transformation transforming a given $n$-qubit state into another must have at least $2×2^n−2$ real degrees of freedom. Hence, in the worst-case scenario, the corresponding quantum circuit should involve at least $2^n+1−2$ elementary rotations, each carrying one degree of freedom.

I can understand that we need atmost $2^n$ complex numbers to describe the state of the $n$-qubit system, and hence $2×2^n$, because we need atleast two real number to form a complex number. But I could not determine how  $2×2^n−2$ comes i.e how we reduce the degrees of freedom by 2.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2\times n^2-2$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying space has dimension $N$, then you need $2N-2$ real parameters to describe arbitrary pure states. One quick way to see it is that you need $N-1$ parameters to specify the $N$ probabilities, and then $N-1$ additional parameters to specify the phases. Equivalently, you start with an arbitrary complex vector in $\mathbb C^N$, which amounts to $2N$ real degrees of freedom, and then remove two degrees of freedom to take into account normalisation and global phase constraints.

An arbitrary unitary in an $N$-dimensional space is specified by $N^2$ real parameters. However, if you only consider the action on a fixed state, many such unitaries become indistinguishable. Then, the number of "effectively different" unitaries becomes equal to the number of pure states that you can produce from the input, which as discussed above is characterised by $2N-2$ real parameters.

If you consider a system with $n$ qubits, then $N=2^n$.